# Android imageview change tint to simulate button click

Tags: android-imageview, android

I have an imageview on which I have set a bitmap fetched from an url.
On the imageview I have set an onClickListener which opens up a dialog.

I want to somehow change the tint (make it darker) when the imageview is pressed upon to provide a sort of button click like feel.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 102):

happydude's answer is the most elegant way to handle this but unfortunately (as pointed out in the comments) the source code for ImageView only accepts an integer (solid colour). [Issue 18220](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=18220) has been around for a couple years addressing this, I've posted a workaround there that I'll summarize here:

Extend ImageView and wrap drawableStateChanged() with code that sets the tint based on the new state:

**TintableImageView.java**

```
package com.example.widgets;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;

import com.example.R;

public class TintableImageView extends AppCompatImageView {

    private ColorStateList tint;

    public TintableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TintableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public TintableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TintableImageView, defStyle, 0);
        tint = a.getColorStateList(R.styleable.TintableImageView_tintColorStateList);
        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();
        if (tint != null && tint.isStateful())
            updateTintColor();
    }    

    private void updateTintColor() {
        int color = tint.getColorForState(getDrawableState(), 0);
        setColorFilter(color);
    }

}
```

Define a custom attribute:

**attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="TintableImageView">
        <attr name="tintColorStateList" format="reference|color" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Use the widget and custom attribute with your local namespace instead of Android's:

**example_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.example.widgets.TintableImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/example"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:tintColorStateList="@color/color_selector"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can then use a colour selector like happydude suggested:

**color_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/pressed_color"/>
    <item android:color="#00000000"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: I'm trying your solution, but still getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "@2130837701"` when a constructor inside `TintableImageView` calls its super... I needed to pass `new int[]{R.styleable.TintableImageView_tint}` because `obtainStyledAttributes` was asking for an array, and to declare `<drawable name="tab_icon_selector">@drawable/tab_icon_selector</drawable>` inside colors.xml in order to be able to reference it from android:tint

Comment: This is why my answer defines a custom tint attribute in attrs.xml. You have to use the custom **app:tint** in your layout instead of **android:tint**. Essentially, you are creating a new attribute that wraps the native one and feeds it one color at a time.

Comment: thanks for answering! I've changed to `app:tint` and the exception is gone... But the selector is still not being used, ie, my icons are black all the time... is my drawable declaration inside colors.xml the correct way to do it?

Comment: Please answer my question on SO, so I can accept it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500039/how-to-use-selector-to-tint-imageview-in-android

Comment: I've provided an answer there. Just as a note for others here, you can put your selector.xml in /res/color to reference it using @color

Comment: @StephenKidson thnk u very much for sharing such useful cod. thnks again

Comment: This doesn't work for me if I use a drawable state list or just a single color resource. How can I tint the ImageView in these cases?

Comment: I removed `mTint.isStateful()` from the `drawableStateChanged()` method and now it works for me for both of the situations i said above, including if they are both done on the same button.

Comment: For those reading that haven't turned to dust waiting for an official fix, it is now supposedly fixed in Android API 21 (Lollipop). Also the fix may someday be [**back-ported to previous APIs through AppCompat**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18220#c13) though I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: I pasted your code and check everything and it just doesn't work.

Comment: @DannySuen did you read my comments above? are you using a drawable state list or single color resource?

Comment: Thank you, buddy. It works perfectly! For those whose app crashes - do not forget to specify your correct package name in xml (instead of  com.example.widgets.TintableImageView)

Comment: Adding `android:clickable="true"` in the custom `ImageView` worked for me

Comment: By clicking image, tint color is not staying it only changing when image is pressesed

Answer (score 8):

One way would be to use a combination of a `ColorFilter` and a `ColorStateList` that contains your tint color for when the button is pressed.  The xml for the `ColorStateList` in the res/color directory would look like this:

button_pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/pressed_color"/>
    <item android:color="#00000000"/>

</selector>
```

where `@color/pressed_color` is your tint color (which should be partially transparent).  Then in your `ImageView` subclass, you apply the color by overriding `drawableStateChanged()`.

```
@Override
protected void drawableStateChanged() {
    super.drawableStateChanged();

    ColorStateList list = getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.button_pressed);
    int color = list.getColorForState(getDrawableState(), Color.TRANSPARENT);
    setColorFilter(color);
    invalidate();
}
```

Any time the button's state changes, this code is called and will automatically set the tint as appropriate.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It doesnt seem to do anything. Using the debugger I noticed that the drawableStateChanged() method is not triggered on onPress but seems to only trigger on onClick.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot see any errors in the code above. By definition, the method should be called when the pressed state changes. I have been using this construct in my own code and it works ok. As a test, in your ImageView XML add `android:tint="@color/pressed_color"`. This should add a permanent tint to your image, as it calls the same colorfilter setting method as the code above. This way you can at least rule out a problem with the color you chose.

Comment: Sorry, I am dumb. You can just add your color state list directly to your `ImageView` XML file directly. See edit above.

Comment: Ok. so this is the error when I get when i set android:tint="@drawable/button_pressed", I get this error during compile,06-19 20:22:54.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2338): Caused by:  java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'res/drawable/button_pressed.xml' as integer
06-19 20:22:54.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):  at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:383)
06-19 20:22:54.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:372)
06-19 20:22:54.222: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):  at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:12s)

Comment: First off, please disregard the "edit."  I looked through the source code and sure enough `tint` will only accept a solid color.  Sorry to lead you down the wrong track.  Second, I tried the code from the original post above in a custom `ImageView` I created and it worked for me.  I tested it by setting the image using `setImageResource(int)`, though I don't see why the other image setting methods would not work.  Finally, make sure that in your XML definition you add `android:clickable="true"`.  Without this line it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to test it out, but you should be able to set an xml with that behaviour as the ImageView drawable, and then set your bitmap as the ImageView background.

Answer (score 0):

For me a simple solution is working, using *setAlpha(180)* in *onClick* event make the image darker, giving the user a feedback that it was clicked or touched.

```
final ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivDocument);
myImage.setImage...(... your image ...); // load your ImageView
myImage.setClickable(true);
myImage.setFocusable(true);
myImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myImage.setAlpha(180);
        doWhateverYouWantHere(v);
    }
});
```

Regarding your XML layout, nothing special.

Answer (score -1):

This code snippet worked for me:

```
porterDuffColorFilter = newPorterDuffColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.cardview_dark_background),PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

imgView.getDrawable().setColorFilter(porterDuffColorFilter);
imgView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```