# Is there an equivalent to setColorFilter() in XML?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'd like to know if a `ColorFilter` can be set in the XML of a `View` or if the only way is to use `setColorFilter()` in Java.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the documentation 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorFilter.html
there is no corresponding xml version for ColorFilter.

I also searched for attributes in documentation with the keys 'color' and 'filter' 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html

Comment: This is incorrect. `tint` works the same as `setColorFilter`

Comment: @MartinKonecny yes, but `tint` is not available on API <21.

Comment: @AlexeyDmitriev `tint` was added in API 1. See my answer for a link to the docs. `tintMode` was added in API 21.

Answer (score 45):

There is; it's called [tint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#tint). It's not available on `View` but is on `ImageView` and `ImageButton`.

If you want to use it with a `selector` [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18724834/2474498) helped me a bunch.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I want - change the drawable's color of an ImageButton.

Answer (score 17):

You can use:

```
android:tint="@color/white"
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no xml equivalent, but on API level 21 you can use the tint attribute. But I assume you don't want to target 21+ devices. Not in a few years at least.

Comment: tint on imageview works fine with support-v7, tested 2.3 and 4.4

Comment: Use app:tint ="" instead of android:tint=""

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use tint and support older versions you can Add `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1` to build.gradle (Don't forget to update Android SDK)

Thanks for the tip @sherpya!

Comment: This is not correct. AppCompatImageView should not be explicitly used since regular Imageview automatically uses it "under the hood". using it wont make any difference at all. ImageView is also the only view that has "tint" built in from api 1 (Meaning that you can set `android:tint` on it no matter what Android version you are targeting)

Comment: Thanks for fixing me. I thought it didn't work when I tried it without AppCompatImageView. Edited Answer

Comment: Np, fallen into the same trap myself. But as far as I know, tint is not exposed to developers using the support library but only from setting the Theme. If I'm wrong please let me know