# ImageView with LayerDrawable consisting of two StateListDrawable not drawing pressed state on one layer

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable

I am trying to extend ImageView using a LayerDrawable as the source.  Each layer consists of a StateListDrawable with one being a ShapeDrawable and the other being a Drawable loaded from resources.

On a user press, the ShapeDrawable fades from a cyan color to white and the icon drawable from it's original color (white) to a drawable with a color filter applied to it, turning it the same cyan color.

The icon always stays the same original color but the ShapeDrawable fades to white.  I have removed the white state from the icon and the cyan color appears, so I'm assuming it's an issue somewhere with the StateListDrawable.  I have also removed the enter and exit fade duration without any success.

The codes is as follows

```
public class DrawerItemIcon extends ImageView {

    private static final String ITEM_ENABLED_COLOR = "#1ABC9C";

    private int mIconResource;
    private StateListDrawable mCircleDrawable;
    private StateListDrawable mIconDrawable;

    public DrawerItemIcon(Context context, int iconResource) {
        super(context);
        mIconResource = iconResource;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(true);
        setImageDrawable(getLayers());
    }

    private LayerDrawable getLayers() {
        Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
        layers[1] = getCircleDrawable();
        layers[0] = getIconDrawable();
        return new LayerDrawable(layers);
    }

    private Drawable getCircleDrawable() {
        mCircleDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
        mCircleDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed},getPressedShapeCircleDrawable());
        mCircleDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled}, getEnabledShapeCircleDrawable());
        mCircleDrawable.setEnterFadeDuration(500);
        mCircleDrawable.setExitFadeDuration(500);
        return mCircleDrawable;
    }

    private ShapeDrawable getPressedShapeCircleDrawable() {
        ShapeDrawable bgDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
        bgDrawable.setShape(new OvalShape());
        bgDrawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        bgDrawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(4);
        bgDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
        return bgDrawable;
    }

    private ShapeDrawable getEnabledShapeCircleDrawable() {
        ShapeDrawable bgDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
        bgDrawable.setShape(new OvalShape());
        bgDrawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        bgDrawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(4);
        bgDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor(ITEM_ENABLED_COLOR));
        return bgDrawable;
    }

    public Drawable getIconDrawable() {
        mIconDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
        mIconDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, getPressedIconDrawable());
        mIconDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled}, getEnabledIconDrawable());
        mIconDrawable.setEnterFadeDuration(500);
        mIconDrawable.setExitFadeDuration(500);
        return mIconDrawable;
    }

    private Drawable getPressedIconDrawable() {
        return getResources().getDrawable(mIconResource);
    }

    private Drawable getEnabledIconDrawable() {
        Drawable selectedDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(mIconResource);
        selectedDrawable.setColorFilter(
        new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.parseColor(ITEM_ENABLED_COLOR), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
        return selectedDrawable;
    }
}
```

Comment: You really ought to be doing this from drawable XML. It would make the code a lot easier to read, which would probably make the bug more obvious.

Comment: @alanv I'll give it a shot with XML tomorrow.  Though this view only makes up a piece of a compound view.  Is there any reason, performance wise or otherwise, why XML would be better over Java?

Comment: @alanv This makes use of a `ColorFilter` which would be impossible to implement in xml. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137612/is-there-an-equivalent-to-setcolorfilter-in-xml#answer-13140944

Comment: @alex Didn't think of that.  My minimum is API 14 and I don't think Tint is in the Support Library.

Comment: @luke-william-duncan Yeah, tint/tintMode has been around since API 1. However, you're right in that `setImageTintList(ColorStateList)` which you would need for the different states was added in API 21

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the contstant state of that drawable. The fix for this is just to add a `.mutate()` call in the `getEnabledIconDrawable()` method.

```
... getResources().getDrawable(mIconResource).mutate();
```

More information on the constant state can be found here: http://www.curious-creature.com/2009/05/02/drawable-mutations/

Answered elsewhere but will put here for future reference.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will check the code tomorrow and see if it works.

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer before checking it out (I was working on other parts and couldn't apply the stash) but it still doesn't work.  Looking at the article, it would make more sense to add this:

selectedDrawable.mutate().setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(
                Color.parseColor(ITEM_ENABLED_COLOR), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));


Since the constant state would surely be the white drawable, no?

Comment: Yes sorry, that's what I meant. Should've given more context. In the code snippet you posted that method is the `getEnabledIconDrawable()` method

Comment: [Here's a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Lna7sJF4) of the code snippet working with the `Drawable#mutate()` being called to the correct drawable