# Invalid int on xml Android color file when launched on a galaxy tab

Tags: android

I have a crash on my android app when I try to launch it on a Galaxy Tab with android 4.1.2. The error is:

```
09-26 21:06:10.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9596): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/color/tw_primary_text_holo_dark.xml"
```

This error doesn't appears on a galaxy s4 with Android 4.2.2 and also on the emulator (phone or tab screen size) with Android 4.1.1.

I've tried to find this **tw_primary_text_holo_dark.xml** file and I can't find it. But there is obvisouly in a primary_text_holo_dark.

Do you have an idea why this appears only on my tab?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran into this same problem, also on a Galaxy Tab.  The problem turned out to be in one of my resource files, which was a copy of simple_list_item_1.xml from [the official android repository](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml), but with the background color changed.  The property in there that was causing the problem was

```
android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
```

but using `android:paddingStart="5dip"` also caused the same crash.  Using `android:paddingLeft="5dip"` works fine.

Comment: I'm wonderful. What fast and easy I found the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem and it was caused by using the `tint` attribute combined with an color selector on a Galaxy Tab device:

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="24dp"
android:layout_height="24dp"
android:tint="@color/tab_color_selector" />
```

The only solution seems to be to create a custom imageview as described here: [Android imageview change tint to simulate button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095222/android-imageview-change-tint-to-simulate-button-click/18724834#18724834)

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally, errors such as those that rise up on me are resolved after a clean of my project and a rebuild on the device.  Sometimes I feel as though the system just gets itself in a bad state and still is trying to reference something that was previous a different asset than it was expecting.

Otherwise, if this is a standing issue beyond that, not sure.  There are some minor differences that I have found in the software side between versions of Jellybean and you might have found one here.

Comment: Thanks for your response Jay. I've tried to clean my project, delete my app and resintall it and the same errors appears. Do you know if i can get around this error?

Comment: You could always catch the NumberFormatException in the code where you  are retrieving the number and put a default in there for a color instead of using the one that they are trying to use if an exception is thrown.  Not sure how great of a workaround it is, but it should suffice for those special cases.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and with the comment of Jesse Crocker I fix it. The problem was about  `android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"`, when I changed that and I used `android:paddingLeft="5dip"`. My app does not crash anymore.