# How to use selector to tint ImageView?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-selector

I want to tint my tabhost's icons using XML, instead of doing it programmatically (I wasn't able to do that anyway)...

I found this thread on SO: [Android imageview change tint to simulate button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095222/android-imageview-change-tint-to-simulate-button-click)

That seems to be a pretty good solution, but I wasn't able to adapt it correctly in my project... I did the following changes:

```
public class TintableImageView extends ImageView {
    private ColorStateList tint;

    public TintableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    //this is the constructor that causes the exception
    public TintableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public TintableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    //here, obtainStyledAttributes was asking for an array
    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, new int[]{R.styleable.TintableImageView_tint}, defStyle, 0);
        tint = a.getColorStateList(R.styleable.TintableImageView_tint);
        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();
        if (tint != null && tint.isStateful())
            updateTintColor();
    }

    public void setColorFilter(ColorStateList tint) {
        this.tint = tint;
        super.setColorFilter(tint.getColorForState(getDrawableState(), 0));
    }

    private void updateTintColor() {
        int color = tint.getColorForState(getDrawableState(), 0);
        setColorFilter(color);
    }

}
```

I also wasn't able to reference `@drawable/selector.xml` at `android:tint`, so I did this at colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="azulPadrao">#2e7cb4</color>
<drawable name="tab_icon_selector">@drawable/tab_icon_selector</drawable>
</resources>
```

My selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" android:tint="#007AFF" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:tint="#007AFF" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:tint="#007AFF" />
<item android:tint="#929292" />
</selector>
```

My tab layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/TabLayout"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/tab_bg_selector">

<com.myapp.TintableImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_gravity="center" android:tint="@drawable/tab_icon_selector"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/TabTextView" android:text="Text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_selector"
          android:textSize="10dip"
          android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_marginTop="2dip"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

#### EDIT

I was getting a `NumberFormatException` for using `android:tint`, when the correct was `app:tint` (after setting `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.myapp"`)... but now I think I'm using my selector in a wrong way, because the icons are all black, no matter the state...
I've tried setting `<drawable name="tab_icon_selector">@drawable/tab_icon_selector</drawable>` from within colors.xml, didn't work

Comment: The init() method should say TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, **R.styleable.TintableImageView**, defStyle, 0);
        tint = a.getColorStateList(R.styleable.TintableImageView_tint);
        a.recycle(); like the original answer did, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In reference to my solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18724834/2136792, there are a few things you're missing:

**TintableImageView.java**

```
@Override
protected void drawableStateChanged() {
    super.drawableStateChanged();
    if (tint != null && tint.isStateful())
        updateTintColor();
}

public void setColorFilter(ColorStateList tint) {
    this.tint = tint;
    super.setColorFilter(tint.getColorForState(getDrawableState(), 0));
}

private void updateTintColor() {
    int color = tint.getColorForState(getDrawableState(), 0);
    setColorFilter(color);
}
```

drawableStateChanged() must be overridden for the tint to be updated when the element's state changes.

I'm not sure if referencing a drawable from a drawable might cause an issue, but you can simply move your selector.xml into a folder "/res/color" to reference it with "@color/selector.xml" (aapt merges both /res/values/colors.xml and the /res/color folder).

Comment: My bad, I haven't pasted full TintableImageView code, it's now complete in the question... I'e simply pasted your code into my class, the only change was at `init()`... by the way, IntelliJ says that setColorFilter() and none of the constructors are never used...

Comment: Debugging my code, I've noticed the following behavior: 1) init() gets called for the 1st time 2) drawableStateChanged() is called, but tint=null, so it doesn't calls updateTintColor() 3) init() is called 3 more times (I'm trying to tint 4 imageviews), but from now on `drawableStateChanged()` doesn't gets called anymore

Comment: Finally I've figured it out! I was using `TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, new int[]{R.styleable.TintableImageView_tint}, defStyle, 0);`, while the correct is `TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TintableImageView, defStyle, 0);`... Thanks for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: Adding `android:clickable="true"` in `ImageView` worked for me

Answer (score 42):

If you're in API 21+ you can do this easily in XML with a selector and [tint](https://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html#DrawableTint):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_grey"
                android:tint="@color/primary" />
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_settings_grey"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: how to make this backward compatible?

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes use `AppCompatImageView` and the `app:tint` xml attribute for compatibility with pre-lollipop devices.

Comment: fyi, this won't work if your drawable is in xml format.

Comment: Use `<shape />` instead of `<bitmap />` if your `src` is a xml format Shape

Answer (score 24):

I implemented this using [`DrawableCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html) from the Android support-v4 library.

With a regular `ImageButton` (which subclasses `ImageView`, so this info also applies to `ImageView`s), using a black icon from the [material icons collection](https://www.google.com/design/icons/):

```
<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/button_add"
  android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_36dp"
  android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
  android:contentDescription="@string/title_add_item" />
```

This is the utility method I created:

```
public static void tintButton(@NonNull ImageButton button) {
    ColorStateList colours = button.getResources()
            .getColorStateList(R.color.button_colour);
    Drawable d = DrawableCompat.wrap(button.getDrawable());
    DrawableCompat.setTintList(d, colours);
    button.setImageDrawable(d);
}
```

Where `res/color/button_colour.xml` is a selector that changes the icon colour from red to semi-transparent red when the button is pressed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:color="@color/red" />

    <item
      android:color="@color/red_alpha_50pc" />

</selector>
```

After the `ImageButton` has been inflated in my activity's `onCreate()` method, I just call the `tintButton(...)` helper method once for each button.

---

I have tested this on Android 4.1 (my `minSdkVersion`) and 5.0 devices, but `DrawableCompat` should work back to Android 1.6.

Comment: Keep in mind that if your selector is using style attributes, these don't seem to be resolved automatically. You will need to call `DrawableCompat.setTheme()` in order to make that happen, and unfortunately, that requires API 21.

Comment: @SkyKelsey Does perhaps using `ContextCompat.getColorStateList()` work instead of using `Resources.getColorStateList()`?

Comment: Yes, thanks. That works. I still have to apply enabled/disabled state manually on API < 21, but this lets me avoid the API >= 21 `setTheme()` call.

Comment: Adding `android:clickable="true"` in `ImageView` worked for me

Comment: I cannot get this to work in API v19 - my ImageButtons are tinted red, irrespective of the colors specified in the selector. Works fine in API v23! @SkyKelsey, what did you mean when you said " I still have to apply enabled/disabled state manually on API < 21". Is there an additional step I am missing? Please describe if so. Thx.

Comment: I used the parent answer to set the color state list, but < 21 won't use it. So I just set the color manually when the button is enabled or disabled like this: https://gist.github.com/skykelsey/00ac66bb7ed71f9806421b40417842fe

Comment: Thank you so much @ChristopherOrr your answer saved my life

Comment: @SkyKelsey you mentioned `DrawableCompat.setTheme()` for API 21. Did it work for you (on API >=21 of course)? If yes, could you elaborate how/when did you call that?

Answer (score 12):

I agree with @Dreaming in Code and I will give an example.

ic_up_small

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@color/comment_count_selected_color" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/comment_count_text_color"/>

</selector>
```

layout/item_post_count_info.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/post_upvote_icon"
    android:layout_width="14dp"
    android:layout_height="14dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_up_small"
    app:tint="@color/post_up_color"/>
```

Attention: We should use **app:tint** instead of *android:tint*.

My support library version is 26.0.2.

app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
```

If we use android:tint, it will crash and the log is like this:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error
>   inflating class 
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
>                                                                         at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
>                                                                         at
>   com.opera.six.viewholder.post.PostCountInfoViewHolder$1.create(PostCountInfoViewHolder.java:29)
>                                                                         at
>   com.opera.six.viewholder.post.PostCountInfoViewHolder$1.create(PostCountInfoViewHolder.java:25)
>                                                                         at
>   com.opera.six.collection.CollectionAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(CollectionAdapter.java:39)
>                                                                         at
>   com.opera.six.collection.CollectionAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(CollectionAdapter.java:19)
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6493)
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5680)
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3962)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:610)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:132)
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:869)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
>                                                                         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1767)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
>                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
>                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
>                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
>                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
>                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
>                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
>                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
>                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
>                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
>                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(Vi

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the hint about app:tint instead of android:tint.

Comment: Hi, You gave selector xml as srcCompat is that correct?

Comment: +1 but the selector XML is a color one, and it is assigned to app:tint; the vector drawable is assigned to app:srcCompat. From what you wrote, it seems that the drawable is a selector, which is not correct.

Answer (score 11):

With support library 22.1 we can use DrawableCompat to tint drawable, API level 4+

> DrawableCompat.wrap(Drawable) and setTint(), setTintList(), and setTintMode() will just work: no need to create and maintain separate drawables only to support multiple colors!

Comment: I agree with you, subclassing ImageView is a hassle and should be avoided if possible. Could you provide a complete example?

Answer (score 4):

With current AppCompat support library, you can use `app:tint` on `ImageView` tag which will be inflated as `AppCompatImageView` and handle the state change properly.

In `AppCompatImageView`, you can see that `mImageHelper` is notified of the state change:

```
@Override
protected void drawableStateChanged() {
    super.drawableStateChanged();
    if (mBackgroundTintHelper != null) {
        mBackgroundTintHelper.applySupportBackgroundTint();
    }
    if (mImageHelper != null) {
        mImageHelper.applySupportImageTint();
    }
}
```

Android Studio currently gives a warning on this, but you can safely suppress it.