# Background Tint Text view not working for pre Lollipop Devices

Tags: java, android

I have downloaded the latest android support library `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1` which I suppose support `android:backgroundTint` for `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView`.
But I can't still get the tint working when I run it on devices lesser than Lollipop.

Here is what I did:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/balloon_outgoing_normal"
    android:backgroundTint="#222"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching on my own, I found a third party library on github that uses a chat bubble and allows background color changing which is similar to the background tint effect. You can check it out on 
https://github.com/himanshu-soni/ChatMessageView

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your activity `extends AppCompatActivity` and your base theme uses any of the `Theme.AppCompat` theme as parent. Then add the following attributes to your base theme with your preferred color choices.

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primary_deepPurple_500</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primary_deepPurple_600</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary_dark_deepPurple_700</item>
<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primary_deepPurple_500</item>
```

The 500, 600 and 700 shades are according to [the Material Design color palette](https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette).

That should tint your buttons.

Btw, [you don't need](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatTextView.html#jd-content) to directly use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` in your layouts, unless when you're creating a custom TextView out of it. Their methods and variables (like the tint feature) are available to you when you extend AppCompatActivity. It is called [polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1031385/1944049).

Comment: I am trying to tint a Text view and not a button. The text view has background drawable, a message bubble precisely. What I want to achieve is to be able to tint the background in pre lollipop devices.

Comment: Not sure, but may be this answer is what your need http://stackoverflow.com/a/29790025/1944049 Also skim the other answers in that thread.

Comment: I was able to get what I want using a third party library in github that uses a chat bubble and allows background color changing which is similar to the background tint effect. https://github.com/himanshu-soni/ChatMessageView

Comment: Cool! Consider posting this comment as an answer, and select it as the best answer so others can find it easily.