# state_pressed not working in color selector for tint for an imageview

Tags: android, android-layout

Code of the view I'm using it in:

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_bookmark_border_black_24dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/author"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/dots"
            android:tint="@color/bookmark_color_selector"
            android:id="@+id/bookmark"/>
```

The code of the color selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@android:color/black" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</selector>
```

More information: I'm using this view inside a cardView which is then used in a recyclerView. The tint of the icon remains white. Does not change(like i want it to) to black on touching it.

Comment: Does it work if you put this selector into ```android:background``` ?

Comment: I've used the android background attribute for the icon.

Comment: Ok I understand but let's try do this and see if then the background changes

Comment: No. Because I'm using a color selector and not a drawable selector.

Comment: Have You Seen This Solution : <https://stackoverflow.com/a/19527747/6022340>

Comment: @Chirag doesn't matter. `android:background` takes color or drawable

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines as well in selector

```
android:background="@color/white" 
android:state_focused="true"
```

Comment: I've used the android background attribute for the icon.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make a number of changes. First, remove these two lines from your `<ImageView>` tag:

```
        android:background="@drawable/ic_bookmark_border_black_24dp"
        android:tint="@color/bookmark_color_selector"
```

And add this line:

```
        android:clickable="true"
```

Then, in your Java code, wherever you inflate this `ImageView` (probably in your activity's `onCreate()` method), add this code:

```
    ImageView bookmark = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bookmark);
    Drawable icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable. ic_bookmark_border_black_24dp);
    ColorStateList tint = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.bookmark_color_selector);
    DrawableCompat.setTintList(icon, tint);
    bookmark.setImageDrawable(icon);
```

What's going on here?

Basically, `ImageView`s don't support tinting based on a selector before API 21, so you have to use support library methods to make it work. The `ContextCompat` methods allow you to access your image and your color selector, and then the `DrawableCompat` method actually applies the tint to the image. Finally, you have to make your `ImageView` "clickable" or else it will never be in the pressed state.

**Edit**
I just noticed that you said you were using this inside a `RecyclerView`. So my Java code posted above will have to be either in `onCreateViewHolder()` or `onBindViewHolder()`. As such, `this` isn't a valid reference to a `Context` instance for the `ContextCompat` methods; instead use `itemView.getContext()`.