# how to apply tint in drawable of selector?

Tags: android, image, layout, selector, shapes

I have 2 images (`normal`,`pressed`), I want to set in selector of button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/recent_pressed" />
    <item
         android:drawable="@drawable/recent" />
</selector>
```

now I want to apply tint color in `@drawable/recent_pressed` image.

can have any solution for this.

I don't want to create custom class for imageview, because this selector is use as a menu.

I searched about that but this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19500039/3678807) not working for me

Answer (score 20):

Create a selector tint_tem.xml :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:color="@color/white" android:state_activated="true" />
<item android:color="@color/green" />
```

Then in your xml, you can add tint attribute to ImageView:

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:tint="@color/tint_item"
android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_home" />
```

ou can also use this selector on a TextView using textColor attibute:

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="@color/tint_item" />
```

Answer (score 8):

> You can create a bitmap and apply tint on it .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/your_pressed_drawable" android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_second_drawable" />
</selector>
```

Comment: yes, but only if the drawable is a bitmap, not if it is another drawable, like vector drawable