# Layered button with transparent icon in Android

Tags: android, button, icons, layer

Is it possible to make layered button in Android with transparent icon throgh first layer? It looks tricky, I could make different assets but is it possible to achieve it programmatically? Example below

[image: Example]

EDIT: Icon has no background, only border.

Answer (score 0):

Seems easy enough. Save the icon as a `.png` file, such that anything besides the arrow outline is transparent. Then it's a simple matter of drawing one ImageView on top of another ImageView, depending on what you want.

In order to tint the arrow, use a TintableImageView as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095222/android-imageview-change-tint-to-simulate-button-click).