# Tint does not work <21 version in DataBinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am using [DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/) to `tint` vector drawable of `ImageView` on basic of an boolean flag. This code works well for >=21 version. But fails in <21 version.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:tint="@{model.nextEnabled ? @color/primary : @color/silver}"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_right_blue_24dp"
    />
```

Here `ic_right_blue_24dp` is a vector drawable.

After checking binding class, I could see that code for <21 version is not getting generated.

> ```
>        if(getBuildSdkInt() >= 21) {
>
>             this.mboundView1.setImageTintList(androidx.databinding.adapters.Converters.convertColorToColorStateList(modelBackEnabledMboundView1AndroidColorPrimaryMboundView1AndroidColorSilver));
>         }
> ```

**I have tried all things I could think, and could find.**

- AppCompatImageView
- ImageView
- `app:srcCompat`
- `android:src`
- `app:tint`
- `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`
- `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);`

**Here I must tell you that all things work using regular `tint` without `binding`.**

Comment: Test case **`app:tint`**

Comment: Yes I tried already, it cause an error. `:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:tint' with parameter type int on androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.`

Comment: Have you tried this [v7/widget/AppCompatImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView)?
 `<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        app:tint="..." ... />`

Comment: @Mykhailo No, I have migrated to `AndroidX`, I believe there is no difference in classes of `AndroidX` and `Support`. Because `AndroidX` was just an rename process. https://stackoverflow.com/q/51280090/6891563

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095222/android-imageview-change-tint-to-simulate-button-click/18724834#18724834

Comment: @MartinZeitler It is an custom view, so binding adapters are not defined for it. and it will sure not work in data binding. thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Khemraj added an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set the tint of an ImageView using databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65058461/set-the-tint-of-an-imageview-using-databinding)

Comment: It is very old question, but I think it does. But it should be resolved by Google.

Answer (score 2):

there still is [custom data-binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters#java). even exactly the method, as requested:

```
@BindingMethods({
    @BindingMethod(
        type = "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView",
        attribute = "android:tint",
        method = "setImageTintList"
    )
})
```

Comment: Martin yes, that's what I managed today. I created BindingAdapter, and set tint programmatically, that works on all versions.

Comment: Android binding library have not added methods for <21 versions yet.

Comment: @Khemraj you could file an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=484080&template=878802

Comment: there is an issue for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65058461 >> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152953070

Answer (score 2):

This BindingAdapter will set tint programmatically...and it worked for me

```
@BindingAdapter("android:tint")
fun AppCompatImageView.setImageTint(@ColorInt color: Int) {
    setColorFilter(color)
}
```

Usage

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:tint="@color/primary"
    ...
    />
```

Comment: Its a BindingAdapter which will set tint programmatically...and it worked for me