# Set the tint of an ImageView using databinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I use databinding to set the tint of my `ImageView`. And this is working well :

```
android:tint="@{plantEntity.isFavorite ? @color/favorite : @color/favorite_none}" />
```

The problem is `android:tint` is deprecated. When I try to use `app:tint` instead, I have this error :

> ```
> Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.ImageView app:color> that accepts parameter type 'int'
>
> If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.
> ```

Why and what I have to do ? Create a `BindingAdapter` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

similar to what has been discussed on [Tint does not work <21 version in DataBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53045802)

add a binding adapter:

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("app:tint")
fun ImageView.setImageTint(@ColorInt color: Int) {
  setColorFilter(color)
}
```

and you don't have to use [any compat](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat) if your minSdk is > 21 (which is a good deal anyway in 2021 you should not support anything below 26)

anyhow .. this seems to be a fug on the [androidx.databinding expression](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions) https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152953070

Comment: No need for the `app:` prefix in the Binding Adapter annotation.

Answer (score 9):

It's working and using `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView`.

And `app:tint` is no more deprecated.

Comment: android:tint is deprecated. but is not deprecated if you use androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView instead of ImageView

Comment: `Must use app:tint instead of android:tint`

Comment: Quite the opposite - use `android:tint`

Answer (score 5):

Use `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView` with `android:tint`.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement @Jéwôm's answer with a clear example, use `AppCompatImageView` with `android:tint`

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tint="@{data.yourImageTintColorRes}"
    android:src="@drawable/yourDrawable"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add variable

```
<variable name="color" type="Integer" />
```

and...

```
android:background="@{color == 0 ? @color/black : color == 1 ? @color/red: @color/purple_200 }"
```

On the code, set the value

```
 binding.color = 0
```